# helm chart failing with service "cert-manager-webhook" not found

Tags: kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

I am trying to deploy [cert-manager/webhook-example](https://github.com/cert-manager/webhook-example/tree/master/deploy/example-webhook) using helm chart.

But getting following error.

```
% helm install cert-manager-webhook ./cert-manager-webhook
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": service "cert-manager-webhook" not found
```

What I am missing here ?